# How can I Represent a list of dictionary in a tabular form in Django in my view.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

```
[{'card pin 0': 4925795801642108,
  'card pin 1': 6184551705968070,
  'card pin 2': 8818636104783618, 
  'card pin 3': 8085277979531543},

{'serial 0': 'WRN7677', 
'serial 1': 'WRN2637', 
'serial 2': 'WRN7464', 
'serial 3': 'WRN7917'}]
```

This is the result I get from these two functions below when called from my **view.py**:

```
def generate_card_serial(total=10, prefix='SCH', length=4):
    range_start = 10 ** (length - 1)
    range_end = (10 ** length) - 1
    times_run = 0
    serial_dict = {}
    while times_run <= total - 1:
        gen1 = randint(range_start, range_end)
        serial_dict.update({'serial' + ' ' + str(times_run): prefix + str(gen1)})
        times_run += 1
    return serial_dict


def generate_card_pin(length_of_pin=16, duplicate=5):
    range_start = 10 ** (length_of_pin - 1)
    range_end = (10 ** length_of_pin) - 1
    pin_dict = {}
    times_run = 0
    while times_run <= duplicate - 1:
        gen1 = randint(range_start, range_end)
        pin_dict.update({'card pin ' + str(times_run): gen1})
        times_run += 1
    return pin_dict
```

What this two functions do is to generate a "10" '4' digit card serial number with a prefix and a "5", '16' digit card pin; and  in this format as shown in the result above.

this is my **view.py** function:

```
def card_gen(request):
    prefix = request.GET["initial"]
    number_of_cards_to_generate = request.GET["total"]
    prefix = str(prefix)
    number_of_cards_to_generate = int(number_of_cards_to_generate)
    card_serial = generate_card_serial(prefix=prefix, total=number_of_cards_to_generate)
    card_pin = generate_card_pin(duplicate=number_of_cards_to_generate)
    card_detail = list([card_pin, card_serial])
    card_detail2 = list_dict(card_detail)
    pprint.pprint(card_detail)

    return render(request, "cardlist.html", {'cardlist': card_detail})
```

I want to be able to represent this in a tabular form in my template. **I've tried but yet to figure it out, please help**.

Can anyone please show me where I am getting it wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show your card_list data as table in your frontend, you need to add below code to your template

```
{% for card in card_list %}
    <table border="2px">
        {% for k, v in card.items %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{k}}</td>
                <td>{{v}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

Here, I have used nested for loop to iterate over the card_list data. First loop to iterate over list of list and second to iterate over dictionary. To know more about loops in django templating check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: Thanks, not long after asking the question, I made some more research, and was able to replicate a somewhat similar answer that's not Django related.